# Moving Negative Sign

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to excel vba and identified an issue with an existing macro used for making updates to a file.

What would be the best way to move a negative sign on a value where insignificant digits are being used for formatting purposes?

Currently, the output is generating a 15 character value (000000000-23378.00) with the negative sign at the front of the significant digit. For this fix I will need to move it to the front of all values...

Example: -00000000023378.00

Logic is as follows...

```
Loop
        Account = Account & String(8 - Len(Account), " ")
        cashamount = CashArray(i, 2)    'Cash
        cashamount = String(15 - Len(cashamount), "0") & cashamount
        cashamount = cashamount & ".00"
        Cusip = "CASHCASH6"             '9 spaces
        Filler = String(10, " ")        'cell padding
        TradeDate = TradeDate           'TradeDate
        filler2 = String(47, " ")       'cell padding
        filler3 = String((970 - 200), " ") 'cell padding

        myDataLine = Account & Cusip & cashamount & Filler & InterestRate & _
            SecType & TradeDate & filler2 & "Cash" & filler3
        Print #hFileOut, myDataLine
    Next i
    Close hFileIn
    Close hFileOut
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do not understand your question at all, but, just to answer what I **think** you're asking, you could search the string for a "-" and, if found, replace it with a "" and then add the "-" to the start of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 2 things to happen... after you determine if you need do do them (you most likely don't need this if statement as it looks like the "-" is constant, but will show it as a JIC).

```
If len(cell(i).value) > len(replace(cell(i).value,"-","")) then
```

First thing:

```
cell(i).value = replace(cell(i).value,"-","")
```

Second thing:

```
cell(i).value = "-" & cell(i).value
```

Should do the trick.